# Number of guess in multiplication quiz

Tags: javascript

I' ve been stuck on a problem for a while and I need your help.
So I am trying to make a multiplication game that is asking a user for an answer so long until he puts 'x' as an answer. (so x is the only answer to end the game). And also the game needs guess counter so when the game finishes the site puts out how many answers were correct and how many were inccorrect and he also get the percantage of succes.
thanks for the help.

```html
<html>
 <head>


 </head>
  <title> Preizkusi svoje znanje poštevanke! </title>

 <body>
   <p> Pozdravljeni, ste pripravljeni preizkusiti svoje znanje poštevanke?</p>
   <script type="text/javascript">

  // ime datoteke:avto.html
  // avtor:Matic Molka
  //Program, ki izbere naključni števili med 1 in 10 ter uporabnika vpraša po njunem zmnožku ter preveri pravilnost uporabnikovega odgovora
  //Vhodni podatki: naključni števili, ki jih zgenerira računalnik in uporabnikov odgovor
  //Izhodni podatki: uporabniku vrne odgovor glede na to ali je odgovor pravilen (čestitamo) ali napačen (narobe)
  
  //Deklariramo in inicializiramo spremenljivke in preverimo njihovo delovanje
  var nakljucna_st1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  //document.write('<p>'+ nakljucna_st1 + '</p>');
  
  var nakljucna_st2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  //document.write('<p>'+ nakljucna_st2 + '</p>');
  
  var zmnožek = nakljucna_st1 * nakljucna_st2
  //document.write('<p>'+ zmnožek + '</p>'); // to je rezultat (zmnožek) prve in druge naključne stevilke
   
  var odgovor = prompt('Koliko je zmnožek ' + nakljucna_st1 + ' in ' + nakljucna_st2 + '?');
  
  if(zmnožek == odgovor){
   document.write('<font color="green"><h1>Čestitamo!</h1></font>');
  }
  else{
   document.write('<font color="red"><h1>Napačno!</h1></font>');
  }
  
  
  
  

  </script>

 
 </body>


</html>
```

Comment: You'll need a loop to start so you repeat asking the question while(prompt != x) , and the a couple of variables to store the count etc.. var something=0;

Comment: while(odgovor != "x") {

Comment: What specific Problems are you having. Any console errors?

Comment: schu34 I just don't know how to write a code to do that. I am trying a while(prompt! = 'x') like Matthew Page suggested but I am not succesful.